# Undefined reference to boost::serialization

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to create some simple server with serialization of structures with use of boost::asio. However I am facing some linker errors while trying to use boost::archives in my project. I get lots of undefined references. Can you please help me to find the error?

```
src/libserver.a(session.cpp.o): In function `boost::archive::text_iarchive::text_iarchive(std::istream&, unsigned int)':
session.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive13text_iarchiveC2ERSij[_ZN5boost7archive13text_iarchiveC5ERSij]+0x25): undefined reference to `boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::text_iarchive_impl(std::istream&, unsigned int)'
```

My project structure is folowing:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── server.cpp
    ├── server.hpp
    ├── session.cpp
    └── session.hpp
```

My root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(mainServer)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

add_subdirectory(src)

find_package(Boost 1.65.1.0 REQUIRED system)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(mainServer main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(mainServer ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(mainServer server)
endif()
```

and my src CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(
    server
    server.cpp
    session.cpp
)

set_target_properties(server PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_include_directories(server PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

And the code which generates linking error in session.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <memory>
#include <message/message.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
{
public:
    Session(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket) : socket(std::move(socket))
    {
    }

    void run();
    void printMessage(const boost::system::error_code &e);
    boost::asio::streambuf stream_buf;

private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
    common::message::Message msg;

    template <typename Handler>
    void readMsg(Handler handler)
    {
        void (Session::*f)(
            const boost::system::error_code &,
            common::message::Message &, boost::tuple<Handler>) = &Session::handle_read_header<common::message::Message, Handler>;
        boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(inboundHeader),
                                boost::bind(f,
                                            this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(msg),
                                            boost::make_tuple(handler)));
    }

    template <typename T, typename Handler>
    void handle_read_header(const boost::system::error_code &e,
                            T &t, boost::tuple<Handler> handler)
    {
        if (e)
        {
            boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
        }
        else
        {
            std::istringstream is(std::string(inboundHeader, headerLength));
            std::size_t inbound_data_size = 0;
            if (!(is >> std::hex >> inbound_data_size))
            {
                boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
                boost::get<0>(handler)(error);
                return;
            }

            inboundData.resize(inbound_data_size);
            void (Session::*f)(
                const boost::system::error_code &,
                T &, boost::tuple<Handler>) = &Session::handle_read_data<T, Handler>;
            boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(inboundData),
                                    boost::bind(f, this,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(t), handler));
        }
    }

    template <typename T, typename Handler>
    void handle_read_data(const boost::system::error_code &e,
                          T &t, boost::tuple<Handler> handler)
    {
        if (e)
        {
            boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                std::string archive_data(&inboundData[0], inboundData.size());
                std::istringstream archive_stream(archive_data);
                boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream);
                archive >> t;
            }
            catch (std::exception &e)
            {
                boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
                boost::get<0>(handler)(error);
                return;
            }
            boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
        }
    }

    static const size_t headerLength{8};
    std::string outboundHeader;
    std::string outboundData;
    char inboundHeader[headerLength];
    std::vector<char> inboundData;
};
```

Comment: If you build manually with `-lboost_serialization`, does it work?

Comment: You need to move your add_subdirectory(src) after the Boost stuff. Otherwise it is not known.

Comment: I tried with following g++ main.cpp src/server.cpp src/session.cpp -lboost_serialization
and same issue.

Comment: If you get _the same_ issue when building manually with `-lboost_serialization`, I'd say your installation is broken.

Comment: I will then try to reinstall it and I will post the results.

Comment: I reinstalled boost according to boost docs, got newest cmake and now the manual build works so I believe there is something wrong with CMake now.

Comment: By default `add_library` creates a shared library. That means if you use Boost in your `server` lib you also need to link to it, e.g. by adding `target_link_libraries(server PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` to your src CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @vre It did the trick. I added ${Boost_LIBRARIES} to server target and it worked! Thank you!!

Comment: One more issue. It is compiling but it gives immediate SEG fault :/ It does not occur while compiling manually.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is a prebuild lib, so you must include it in your find command:
`find_package(Boost 1.65.1.0 REQUIRED system serialization)`

Only searching for Boost and Boost::system will only include the header files of boost and the system library, but not the binaries of the serialization library.
The reason it compiles is, that the serialization headers are included by Boost::boost, but it fails to link, since you don't link to the implementation.

Comment: I added this to my root CMakeLists, moved add_subdirectory(src) after the find_package as it was suggested by @vre and still same issue :/

Comment: You are using the shared libs of boost, can you test to change the `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to `ON` or make sure, your boost binaries (.dll / .so) files are in your global path.